# How to make a unique text for each click?

Tags: reactjs

When I click on the gray block, I get text. I want to make it different for each block (especially if there are many blocks). I've read something about `this.props.children` but I can't do it on my own. Can you help me, please?

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-browser-fdgv8?file=/src/Main.js

Answer (score 2):

Props are values or functions passed down to child components from it's parent, to use it in your case you should change this line in App.js

```
 {this.state.isClicked ? <Info info={"text"} /> : null}
```

to

```
 {this.state.isClicked ? <Info info={this.props.text} /> : null}
```

And these lines in Main.js

```
<App/>
<App/>
<App/>
```

to

```
<App text="text" />
<App text="2nd text" />
<App text="3rd text" />
```

This will allow you to display different text on each click.

Going forward you may want to eventually make it somewhat more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass text into the constructor of each block (App class) by creating a Prop attribute.

Main.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import App from "./App";

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        // Create text attributes with your string
        <App text="new" />
        <App text="to" />
        <App text="reactjs" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Info from "./Information";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // create text variable and have it equal the text pass in
    this.text = props.text;
    this.state = {
      isClicked: false
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      isClicked: !this.state.isClicked
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="block" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
          <p style={{ color: "#fff" }}>CLICK</p>
        </div>
         // set the info tag to the text variable create within the class
        {this.state.isClicked ? <Info info={this.text} /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Props are not HTML attributes, because JSX is not HTML.